# Python IndexError: list assignment out of range

Tags: python

I wrote the following code in order to design an algorithm that returns the size of each possible substring in a list:

```
def ejercicio2(list):
    vseq = []
    vseq[0:len(list)] = [1]  # Pone valores de la lista a 1

    i = 1
    while i < len(list):
        aux = i - 1
        while aux >= 0:
            if list[i] > list[aux]: # Si el valor de la lista en i es mayor que el de aux
                vseq[i] = vseq[aux] + 1
                break
            aux -= 1
        i += 1
    return vseq
```

At first, I thought this should work just fine, but everytime I try to run it I get the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prac1.py", line 17, in <module>
    ejercicio2([210, 816, 357, 107, 889, 635, 733, 930, 842, 542])
  File "prac1.py", line 10, in ejercicio2
    vseq[i] = vseq[aux] + 1
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

I know this is likely to be a easy to fix issue, but I don't seem to find a solution, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `vseq[0:len(list)] = [1]` expands `vseq` to be `[1]`. It does not create a list of `1` elements of the same length as `list`. Slice assignments *do not repeat elements*.

Comment: Do you want to return the length of longest string from the list of strings?

Comment: I want te return the whole list with the substring lengths of each one of the values of the initial list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vseq[0:len(list)] = [1]` does not create a list of length `len(list)`. Since `vseq` is *empty*, the assignment slice is empty too, but you then assign 1 element to it. This results in a list with the same length as the right-hand-side list:

```
>>> import sys
>>> vseq = []
>>> vseq[0:sys.maxsize] = [1]
>>> vseq
[1]
```

If you wanted to create a list with all `1` values, use multiplication:

```
vseq = [1] * len(list)
```